# SQL Expression with Multiple Values Parameter in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, sql, parameters

I`m trying to select many values from the parameter "Estado" which will be use in the query in the code. This parameter has a value list, string type.

I think it`s a format() problem...But also I will have problems to put in the SQL expression format: 'VALUE1','VALUE2'.

I tried with .split(';'), but do not work.

```
import arcpy

Layer1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
Tabela1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 
Estado = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2).split(';') 
Ano = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3).split(';')  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
Saida = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
stats = []

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):   
    lyr.name = Layer1
    lyr.definitionQuery = """UF IN ({})""".format(Estado)

for field in arcpy.ListFields(Tabela1):
    if field.name in (Ano):
        stats.append([field.name, "SUM"])

arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Layer1, Saida, stats, "")        
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

When I tried to run the script, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\AgroBD.gdb\M6a.py", line 19, in <module>
    arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Layer1, Saida, stats, "")
 File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", 
line 1160, in Statistics
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used. [Brasil_Municipios]
An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT * FROM Brasil_Municipios WHERE UF 
IN ([u'AC', u'AM'])]
An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used. [Brasil_Municipios]
An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT OBJECTID FROM Brasil_Municipios 
WHERE UF IN ([u'AC', u'AM'])]
The table was not found. [out3]
Failed to execute (Statistics).

Failed to execute (Script1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's split method turns a string into an array for your variable Estado.

When you call String.format in python, it simply uses the built-in array to string conversion, which formats Estado as `[u'AC', u'AM']`. The square brackets and the `u` character are likely what's causing you problems.

Instead of relying on python's built-in array to string conversion (implicitly called by format()), you should use join() to control how the string is created.